# Order of operations when expanding shell expressions with xargs

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I am trying to replace some bytes in a binary file using this rather long expression

```
objdump --show-raw-insn -d libc-2.30.so | grep -w movdqa | awk '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)}' | xargs -I {} sh -c "printf '\xf3' | dd of=$mybinary bs=1 seek=$((0x{})) count=1 conv=notrunc;"
```

In this expression, `$((0x{}))` is evaluated by the shell before xargs replaces `{}` with the hexadecimal value of the byte to be overwritten. `$((0x{}))` replaces a hex value with a decimal value, e.g. 0xF to 16.

```
-bash: 0x{}: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "{}")
```

How can I get xargs to run its substitution before bash tries to expand `$((0x{}))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the xargs portion of the expression in single quotes instead of double quotes solved the issue. The shell will not expand expressions in single quotes and must therefore wait to be invoked by xargs before expanding expressions. Printf also needed the quotes swapped to reflect this change.

```
objdump --show-raw-insn -d libc-2.30.so | grep -w movdqa | awk '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)}' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'printf "\xf3" | dd of=libc-2.30.so bs=1 seek=$((0x{})) count=1 conv=notrunc;'
```